# PHP array minor problem

Tags: php, arrays

I'm really not sure how to explain this. It's so simple I can't fathom why it's not working.

I have a loop. It puts a bunch of strings into an array. If I fill a single variable with any given string, it will output it perfectly.

But filling *an array* with the strings will make it give me the dreaded:

`Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array`

Note: my strings are not all 'Array'.

The way I loop is:

```
 while(...)
 {
     $arr[] = $resultFromLoop;
 }
```

Here is my var_dump.

```
    array(1) {
      ["tagName"]=>
      string(5) "magic"
    }
    array(1) {
      ["tagName"]=>
      string(4) "nunu"
    }
    array(1) {
      ["tagName"]=>
      string(5) "books"
    }
    array(1) {
      ["tagName"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    array(1) {
      ["tagName"]=>
      string(3) "zzz"
    }
    array(1) {
      ["tagName"]=>
      string(4) "grey"
    }
    array(1) {
      ["tagName"]=>
      string(3) "new"
    }
    array(1) {
      ["tagName"]=>
      string(6) "flight"
    }
```

Comment: Could you post a more detailed code excerpt? You didn't give much to work with.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you're working with array as with a string.

> It puts a bunch of strings into an array.

Nope, there are no strings. I already gave you a magic `var_dump($resultFromLoop)` function, but you're too lazy to use it for debugging your code (because there is SO, where you can ask any question and don't bother yourself with thinking)

Comment: I already tried var_dump, otherwise I wouldn't be asking. It returns a proper looking array. Maybe you could just answer my question once and I can just learn and never ask the same one again instead of having to repeat myself a half-dozen times until somebody gives me the line of code that Google and php.net cannot.

Comment: @Sennheiser: `var_dump($resultFromLoop); var_dump($arr);` --- copy the result as-is to your question.

Comment: @Sennheiser: so `$resultFromLoop['tagName']` is a string, and `$resultFromLoop` is an array. As I said - `var_dump()` can help you to debug your code without SO.